# jQuery to FadeOut Background image declared by HTML inline style

Tags: jquery, html, styles, inline, fadeout

I've been trying to use Jquery to `fadeOut` only the background image in a div that's declared via inline style and not CSS. For example:

```
<div class="big-video-wrap-image" style="background:url(images/image1.jpg) repeat;">
```

How should I go about applying a fade out effect to the div class's background style so that the div remains but only the background image is gone (by fading out).

---

Possibly unnecessary info:
To share what I'm wanting to do this for will bring up some additional issues but I'm hoping sharing these details will paint a complete picture of what I'm doing.

I'm using:

- Jquery 1.8.3
- Modernizr 2.6.2
- Cycle 2.9
- Easing 1.3
- prettyPhoto
- BigVideo.js with all dependency libraries.

[BigVideo.js](http://dfcb.github.com/BigVideo.js/) displays a dynamically sized video in the background of a website (or theoretically any div).

But it doesn't work well with mobile devices.  So I'm using Modernizr to check for devices so the script to run BigVideo.js is setup like this:

```
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
if (Modernizr.touch) {
} else {
    BV.init();
    BV.show($('.big-video-play').attr('data-video'),{altSource:$('.big-video-play').attr('data-video2')});
    $(".big-video-wrap-image").attr('[style*="background"]') /*No idea what should be on this line*/

}
```

the html as such:

```
<div class="big-video-wrap big-video-play" data-video="vids/vid1.mp4" data-video2="">
<div class="big-video-wrap-image" style="background:url(images/ally1.jpg) repeat;">
```

and External CSS as such:

```
.big-video-wrap {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.big-video-wrap-image {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is being used in a responsive website layout.
So that's how it's setup right now and both the bigvideo.js throws the video at the top of the master body div instead of the correct div class and of course making the firstframe/mobile image fade upon video loading isn't working either.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create an image to position over the div. Then take away the background style and fade out the image.

```
var $imageDiv = $(".big-video-wrap-image"),
    bgUrl     = $imageDiv.css('background-image').split('(')[1].replace(')', '') //Should probably be done in another way, feel free to fill in anyone,
    imgDummy  = new Image();

imgDummy.onload = function () {
    $(this).addClass('dummyImg').insertBefore($imageDiv).fadeOut();
    $imageDiv.removeAttr('style');
};

imgDummy.src = bgUrl;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/SkQ2Y/1/

Comment: Well that works to fadeOut an image... but not in the way I'm looking for... to show you what the original look is before fade please see this image link: [IMGUR image link](http://i.imgur.com/t09TCUd.jpg). Putting the image in the top corner like that over everything will not work well. There's got to be a way to fadeout a image in a div background without fading out the entire div and child divs... ??

Comment: But why can't you just place something just above the background div? Or maybe I don't understand...

Comment: Maybe it's me who's not understanding.. lol okay, so then how can I place an image over the background div that repeats but yet doesn't cover over all the child divs? Example if I use the above script on the div it renders my background image over all child divs without a repeat then fades out. It doesn't look seem-less or nice that way. Basically just need that div background image as it is after the page loads to fadeOut. My problem besides others, how to point Jquery to any background image used in whatever class or ID so all I have to do is add ".fadeOut('fast')" at the end of the js line.

Comment: Aha ok so place the dummy img behind the div instead? And set background on the div to transparent.

Comment: That would work! I'll give it a try.. it's a responsive page so not sure what artifacts this will cause. And because repeat doesn't work the same on images as it does on div background.. maybe I can just put another Div behind it? hmmm

Comment: This kinda works:
`
.big-video-wrap-image {
position: absolute;
height: 636px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.big-video-wrap {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
`
`
<div class="big-video-wrap-image" style="background:url(images/ally1.jpg) repeat;"></div>
<div class="big-video-wrap big-video-play" data-video="vids/vid1.mp4" data-video2="">
`

the issue is the height has to be given in CSS which needs to be dynamic as different divs of class "big-video-wrap" will have different heights.

Comment: `$('.container').equalHeights();` won't work because one of them is not a child div.

so I tried this:
`var rsh1=document.getElementById('.big-video-wrap');
var rsh2=document.getElementById('.big-video-wrap-image');
rsh2.style.height = rsh1.style.height;`

and that didn't work either.
Any ideas on the div height issue?
Gotta make them match in height. ty for for all your help so far @tbleckert

Comment: To set the height to the same as the div, you can just do $(this).height($imageDiv.outerHeight()); inside the load event on the image. I don't know how the end result should be. But if you need to update the height on the image, then you can do it on window resize event.